# Simple Webapp for editing an XML file

Tags: xml, apache, web-applications

I have a very simple xml file that looks something like this:

```
<teams>
    <team lead="jim" wing="bob" />
    <team lead="frank" wing="mary" />
    <team lead="george" wing="hans" />
</teams>
```

I need to let people edit this file using a web interface, preferably served over apache. It should just list the "lead" and "wing" attributes in a table and allow them to be edited as free-form text. Before I start mucking about and writing my own, is there some kind of super-simple framework that does this kind of thing out of the box? Liker a general purpose web-based xml editor, where you could set the path to a file and the xpath of the attributes to be edited and they would show up on a nice web form...preferably open source.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [Google Forms](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/forms/)? They allow you to export to various formats the form results.

Comment: Thanks, but I need something I can install on the server where the xml file lives.

Comment: If you're looking for a framework, it's going to be general-purpose. It'd be much easier to hack up a little PHP script than take the trouble of installing a framework and then maintaining it until and unless you see some scope of this utility turning into a full-fledged application in future.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of hoping someone knew of something that already existed - a general purpose web-based xml editor, where you could set the path to a file and the xpath of the attributes to be edited and they would show up on a nice web form. ...Thought it was worth asking.

Comment: Maybe, you should add this to question -- it may elicit more answers, at least more helpful for you :)